# Смена изображения при наведении на другой объект

Tags: javascript, html, css

Мне нужно сделать так чтобы изображение в кнопке менялось при наведении на кнопку.
Вот код:

```
<button class="followed-button">
    <img src="../img/heart.png" class="follow-img">
</button>
```

Comment: Это не код, а разметка. Что вы пробовали и что именно у вас не получилось?

Comment: Смотрите событие `mouseenter`.

Comment: @ΝNL993 `button.followed-button:hover > img.follow-img { content: url(./image.png); }`! Не надо событий.

Answer (score 1):

Без JS можно сделать что-то такое

HTML:

```html
<button class="followed-button">
  <img src="" class="default"/>
  <img src="" class="on-hover"/>
</button>
```

CSS:

```css
.followed-button > .default {
  display: block; /* или другое нужное значение */
}

.followed-button > .on-hover {
  display: none;
}

.followed-button:hover > .on-hover {
  display: block; /* или другое нужное значение */
}

.followed-button:hover > .default {
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: С помощью css можно делать всего за одно правило. Вы что-то затягивали.

Comment: И html менять не нужно будет.

Comment: Ваша правда. Но все же вопрос новичковый, имхо лучше делать решение по-очевидней